# Pop-up image with live text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

What I'm trying to do is have a cool little window or image with live text in it pop up like an alt, except I want it to open when you roll over a specific line of text.

Suggestions anyone?

Comment: You have not mentioned what language or even what context you are referring to. I assume from the 'alt' that you are talking HTML here.

Comment: of course... I was thinking about jquery... It really doesn't matter tho... something quick and easy... Maybe if you could direct me to a good site with a quick tutorial..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article on doing tooltips style popups. That should get you started and you can adapt it to the window layout that you want.

http://www.web-graphics.com/mtarchive/001717.php